# SSH and certificates - how to connect?

Tags: ssh

My geeky friend has dropped me this message:

*Debian instance has been created for you with IP address of `10.5.0.95`. Remember: To connect to it, you need the certificate:
`ssh -i xxx.xxx admin@10.5.0.95`.
The certificate is in the root home of `10.5.0.20` -> I showed you this instance and you can connect to it any time.*

Unfortunately I have no idea about how to connect to this Debian instance using the given information. Those certificates and `ssh` - I can't really understand that.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at an [SSH key use guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys). Basically, you need to connect to the IP address `10.5.0.20` as the `root` user to get access to the **private key** (*not* "certificate"), which is used to connect as `10.5.0.95` as the `admin` user.

Other information sources:

- Comprehensive, complex [Arch Linux wiki SSH Keys article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_Keys)
- `man ssh`